# Using OpenCV and OpenGL for Augmented Reality with Fisheye Camera

Tags: augmented-reality

I want to try augmented reality applications on opencv and opengl
I have a 170 degree FOV fisheye camera.

I want to draw a 3D polygons with these libraries.

I'm trying put distortion coeffs on opengl
Also ı want to use opencv camera matrix --> opengl perspective projection matrix

I'm trying 3d mesh polygons with opencv on distorted images (my camera model scaramuzza) .I get freezing when the polygons start to go out of frame. very low fps problem

But I don't success this process.
what way can i follow?

Comment: have you any experience in either OpenGL or OpenCV?

Comment: "I'm trying put distortion coeffs on opengl with opencv camera matrix." What does that mean? The camera distortion model used by openCV is a non-linear operation which cannot be represented by simple matrix multiplication, and GPU rasterizers will only rasterize polygons with straight edges anyway (by definition), so just distorting the vertex coordinates will not work either.

Comment: @RoQuOTriX yes I have experience but not enough

Comment: @derhass okey ı want to learn another way this problem solution. I'm trying 3d mesh polygons with opencv on distorted images (my camera model scaramuuzza) .I get freezing when the polygons start to go out of frame. very low fps problem.